# A way to increase Transmission upload speed to take all bandwith?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I am using Transmission torrent client on Ubuntu. My upload speed never gets higher than 15% of available upload speed, even if I'm not using computer at all. How can I force Transmission to use all available bandwidth, if it's possible?

I have triple checked all the settings and preferences before asking. I don't have any limitations in settings.

Comment: Are you really concerned about you *upload* speed? Are you sure there are enough requests to saturate your uplink? Are there other seeders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some points to check (to confirm we have set of common things to discuss):

1 - You normally would not worry much about upload speed (you may be interested in download speed more) unless you are initial distributor of torrents

2 - Upload Speed depends on how famous (most wanted) the torrents you added is amongst users (Have you added some of such torrents)

3 -  The bandwidth you obtained from your ISP might not be symmetric (the download rate and upload rate might not be the same). So you are talking about 15% of bandwidth according to your contract with ISP?

Comment: Thank you for response. 1) I just wanted good network not to be wasted when I was away. 2) That's probably correct answer. 3) I meant 15% of measured upload speed (via speedtest.net).